# Scala Future and Either Transformation

Tags: scala, future, seq, either

I have a variable of type

```
val input: Future[Seq[Either[ErrorClass, Seq[WidgetCampaign]]]] = ???
```

I want to traverse this input and remove all duplicates `WidgetCampaign` and return the output as

```
val result: Future[Either[ErrorClass,Set[WidgetCampaign]]] = ???
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Which `ErrorClass` do you want to use in the result if there are multiple values in the outer `Seq`?

Comment: @Tim it can be any one of it, i.e. any instance of ErrorClass from the sequence. Since if there is a nerror, the whole operation needs to be cancelled.

Comment: If you do not check that error code until this second phase of processing then you will perform all the operations to create each element of the `Seq` even if one of the earlier operations fails. It might be worth looking at how that `Seq` is created and stopping that process early when there is an error.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the processing can all be done inside the `Future` using a `map` call:

```
input.map(process)
```

So the problem is to write a `process` function that converts between `Seq[Either[ErrorClass, Seq[WidgetCampaign]]` and `Either[ErrorClass, Set[WidgetCampaign]]`.

Start by making a couple of type aliases to make the rest of the code cleaner.

```
type InType = Either[ErrorClass, Seq[WidgetCampaign]]
type OutType = Either[ErrorClass, Set[WidgetCampaign]]
```

The process itself can be done with an awkward `flatMap` call, but a simple recursive function is probably best:

```
def process(input: Seq[InType]): OutType = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[InType], res: Set[WidgetCampaign]): OutType =
    rem match {
      case Nil => // Stop when no more elements to process
        Right(res)
      case Left(e) :: _ => // Stop on first error
        Left(e)
      case Right(s) :: tail => // Add this Seq to the result and loop
        loop(tail, res ++ s)
    }

  loop(input.toList, Set.empty[WidgetCampaign])
}
```

This is a standard pattern for recursive logic where the recursive function itself is wrapped in an outer function. The inner function is then tail-recursive for efficiency, with the intermediate result being passed down through the recursive call.

The input is converted to a `List` to make pattern matching easier.

This is untested, but it compiles so that's a start...